# AngularJS $Http not triggered on Edge/IE

Tags: angularjs, debugging, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-edge

I have the following code, which works perfectly fine on Mozilla, Chrome, but not on Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer. Here is what happens.

When user loads a webpage I trigger the following code:

```
    $http.get("/api/items")
        .then(function (response) {
            angular.copy(response.data, $scope.items);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = error.statusText;
        })
    .finally(function () {
        $scope.isBusy = false;
    });
```

which pulls all the values into the `<ul>`. This part works normally on all browsers. However when I trigger the following one:

```
    $scope.interval = $interval(function () {
        $http.get("/api/items")
            .then(function (response) {
                //success

                //loop through the response
                angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) { ... more code here}
```

then suddenly the response is no longer from my web api. What I mean is, that when I was debugging my application and placed breakpoint in my GET api (I mean under Visual Studio in my MVC Controller) I could not see the get call being triggered from Microsoft Edge.

Here is what network inspector looks like from Chrome:

[image]

and this one is from Edge:

[image]

As far as I understand, Edge has only made one real XHR call towards my GET, and all the remaining ones are just cached from memory?

How can one solve this problem? Why is this even happening?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out, that the problem is with Angular with storing Cache. There are two options one can use (taken from other StackOverflow posts):

1) Angular Method (which for unknown reason did not work for me):

```
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    

    // Answer edited to include suggestions from comments
    // because previous version of code introduced browser-related errors

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

2) The ASP.NET way of decorating GET method:

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```